# Split list at point where a Boolean value repeats n times

Tags: python, list, time-series, nan

I have two lists which have the time and value for a time series. There is a corresponding list that contains Boolean values that identify where the NAN values are in the time series. What I need to do is if a True value (i.e. NAN value) repeats over 5 times (6 NAN values in a row), split the list into two (at the start and the end of the sequence, so there are no NAN values in the two resulting lists. So basically, I need to split the list into a list of smaller lists, that start and end where there was a gap that contained more than 6 repeating NAN values. I tried something along the lines of:

```
    for i in range(len(nan_list)-5):
        if nan_list[i] == True and nan_list[i+1] == True and nan_list[i+2] == True and nan_list[i+3] == True and nan_list[i+4] == True and nan_list[i+5] == True:
```

I'm not really sure what the best way is to go from here, and I'm sure there is a better way.

Then what I need to do, is for an occurrence of a repeating NAN value that repeats less than 5 times (6 NAN values in a row), replace these values with values that are calculated using b-spline from scipy. I'm not quite sure how to go about this. Thanks!

Comment: Don't you think that pasting code is better than describing code?

Comment: Please format your question: use paragraphs, use examples,... Would you like to read a question like that?

Comment: Sorry, is that a bit clearer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correclty, you want to split one list based on the indices of another (assumingly a list with the same length) in such a way that `n` repeated elements in that other list define where a slice should occur. An 'elegant', but not the most performant way would be to just iterate through `n`-sized slices of your other list and check if `all(nan_list[i:i+n])` at the current index - if yes, put everything from the first list that is before that index as a slice into your results, then skip ahead `n` places and repeat the process. I'd however prefer a procedural approach:

```
def split_list(source, nan_data, nan_len=6):
    result = []  # a list for our final result
    last_pos = 0  # holds the last sliced position
    counter = 0  # a counter for sequential NaNs
    for i, is_nan in enumerate(nan_data):
        if not is_nan:  # encountered a non-NaN, check how many consecutive NaNs we had
            if counter >= nan_len:  # we have a match...
                result.append(source[last_pos:i-counter])  # add a new slice to our result
                last_pos = i  # set the new slice position
            counter = 0  # reset the counter
        else:
            counter += 1  # NaN found, increase the counter
    # find the last slice, if any
    left_over = source[last_pos:] if counter < nan_len else source[last_pos:-counter]
    if left_over:
        result.append(left_over)
    return result  # return the result
```

Then you can use it to split any `source` list based on `nan_len` consecutive `True` values (or any values that evaluate to True) in the `nan_data` list, for example:

```
base_list = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10",
             "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"]
nan_list = [True, False, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True,
            False, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, True, False]

print(split_list(base_list, nan_list, 3))
# [['01', '02', '03', '04'], ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16'], ['20']]
```